# Optimizing an algorithm to find a zero bit in a `uint64_t` word

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a requirement to keep track of free/in-use state of 64K items. My plan is to use `uint64_t array[1000]` with each bit representing an item. I will set a corresponding bit when an item is in-use and will reset when it is free.

To find out a free slot I can scan through the array one by one  and find a bit which is not set, which is the naive and slowest one. One level optimization is to skip words which are full. i.e. those items with value of max_int (of `uint64_t`).

I am looking for means to further optimize this so that I can find the free slot in minimum number of operations.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the negative ratings? A note before -ve rating would be nice.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more specific, and removed reference to recommendations. This has already been answered and the answer has been accepted. I believe this question adds value to the SO user and requests it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there're 64 bits in the number, scanning *log<sub>2</sub>64*=6 times is enough:

```
int findZeroBit(uint64_t n){
int index = 0;
n = ~n;
if (n & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) index += 32;
if (n & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) index += 16;
if (n & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) index += 8;
if (n & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0) index += 4;
if (n & 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC) index += 2;
if (n & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) index += 1;
return index;
}
```

Only one bit will be returned, though.